# How can I limit an org-mode clock out, to some specified time of day?

Tags: org-mode

I use org-mode clocks extensively for task tracking, with one exception. End of day. Depending on my location, amount of haste (trains or battery power) etc. I sometimes neglect clocking out at day end.

Is there a setting to set the maximum allowed day-time (same day) end?

Example: I start an action at 16:35, I run for a train at 17:45. I forgot to log out. On clocking in the next morning - I don't want the keep value of working on the last action overnight, but to a maximum time of say 17:30.

Comment: I deleted my answer with `kill-emacs-hook`. At first sight I overlooked your statement that you forgot to log out. In that case `kill-emacs-hook` does not help. Sorry.

Comment: I have replaced my wrong answer (`kill-emacs-hook`) with an answer that meets your specification quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following advice of `org-clock-in` does quite exactly what you want.
If the clock from yesterday or before is still running you are clocked-out at the time `org-clock-out-latest-back-dated` on the day the clock started.

```el
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Just for customization of `org-clock-out-latest-back-dated':
(defun time-string-hh:mm-validate (time)
  "Returns nil if TIME has the correct format hh:mm.
Where hh are the digits of the number of hours and mm are the digits of the number of minutes.
TIME can be a string or a widget."
  (let ((val (if (stringp time) time (widget-value time))))
    (if (and (stringp val)
         (string-match "^\\([0-9]\\{1,2\\}\\):\\([0-9]\\{1,2\\}\\)$" val)
         (< (string-to-number (match-string 1)) 24)
         (< (string-to-number (match-string 2)) 60))
    nil
      (if (stringp time)
      time
    (widget-put time :error "String does not match format hh:mm.")
    time))))

(define-widget 'time-string-hh:mm 'editable-field
  "Time string with format hh:mm."
  :size 5
  :format "Time (hh:mm): %v "
  :validate 'time-string-hh:mm-validate)

(defcustom org-clock-out-latest-back-dated "17:30"
  "Time as string with format hh:mm to check out on back-dated days."
  :group 'org-clock
  :type 'time-string-hh:mm)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; The actual advice:
(defadvice org-clock-in (before clock-out-back-dated activate)
  "If there is a running clock from a back-dated day
clock it out at `org-clock-out-latest-back-dated' on that day."
  (when (and (org-clocking-p)
         (> (time-to-days (current-time)) (time-to-days org-clock-start-time)))
    (let ((time (decode-time org-clock-start-time))
      (hhmm (mapcar 'string-to-number (progn
                        (when (time-string-hh:mm-validate org-clock-out-latest-back-dated)
                          (error "Wrong time format in `org-clock-out-latest-back-dated'"))
                        (split-string org-clock-out-latest-back-dated ":")))))
      (setf (nth 1 time) (cadr hhmm))
      (setf (nth 2 time) (car hhmm))
      (org-clock-out nil nil (apply 'encode-time time)))))
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias, this is the missing param I was hoping I overlooked. I kept searching for "day end" type keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You could schedule a command to clock out at 17:30.  [Midnight Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightMode) lets you schedule commands to run at a specified time.

Comment: Midnight mode looks helpful, thanks. Will use that to run my weekly cleanup scripts.